# скролл через jQuery

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Для прокрутки блоков на сайте использую [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html), но он виснячит и лагает.
Подскажите пожалуйста другие хорошие плагины.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)
2. [perfect-scrollbar](http://noraesae.github.com/perfect-scrollbar/)
3. [jScrollbar](http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/jscrollbar/)

Answer (score 0):

[Кроссбраузерная кастомизация системного скроллбара](http://habrahabr.ru/company/2gis/blog/169359/)